# Format Time Requires API error

Tags: android

I try to format the time in my model class. It requires the first line or the error occurs. Can anyone help?

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
     public String getFormattedTime() {
             SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("h a");
             // Visit this link for demanded Date&Time formats
             // https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html
             formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(getTimeZone()));
             // Here requires a method to set the TimeZone in Main Activity (info gotten from online
             // resources database)
             Date dateTime = new Date(getTime() * 1000);
             return formatter.format(dateTime);
         }
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Call requires API level 24

Comment: The strange thing is I used this code for other model class in the same project, and it's perfectly OK.

Comment: Check import's or spelling, I'm too lazy to verify it, but I think there must be some different SimpleDateFormat available in lower APIs, or it's spelled tiny bit differently.

Comment: Yup, I guess you must be calling wrong `SimpledateFormat`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using this [SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) that resides under following package

```
android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat
```

which requires API level of 24 or higher. Try using this [SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) instead which is under

```
java.text.DateFormat
```

Comment: OK that's it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

according to this page
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/text/SimpleDateFormat.html
simpledatetimeformat was added in api level 24, that's why you have to add the requiresapi attribute

Comment: The strange thing is I used this code for other model class in the same project, and it's perfectly OK. –